# How to grant access to a sharepoint group using Power Automate 'Grant access to an item or a folder' action

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, flow, power-automate, unique-permissions

I am using 'Grant access to an item or a folder' action to grant access to users at SharePoint list item level.

Now the requirement is to grant access to SharePoint Group as well. How can I pass the group as parameter here in the action to grant access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation at: [Grant access to an item or a folder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#grant-access-to-an-item-or-a-folder),

`Recipients` has type email and expects the Email address or users or Microsoft 365 groups, etc.

So as per my understanding, you will not able to able to grant access to SharePoint group using this action.

**Workaround**:

You can use SharePoint REST API in `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` action to grant access to SharePoint group on list item. You need to use below endpoint:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<List Name>')/items(<List Item ID>)/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid='<Group Principle ID>', roleDefId=<Role Definition ID>)
```

Example:

[image]

**Reference**: [Set SharePoint List Item Permissions Using MS Flow](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/set-sharepoint-list-item-permission-using-ms-flow/)

Comment: This gives me error when trying to give an individual user permissions on the list item using their email address as the `principalid` value:  `Input string was not in a correct format`.  Does anyone know how to use this action to assign an individual user permissions on the list item?  The reason we are looking at this approach is that `Grant access to an item or a folder` action is not working when we define a custom permission level role id - it is only working with out of the box permission level role ids.

Comment: Can you show us the endpoint (Uri) you are using? [Ask new question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) by providing more details and screenshot of flow if possible.